# Shrink table to fit columns?

Tags: tabulator

I have a table with all fixed width columns.  The problem is the table expands to the width of the container, while the columns are justified against the left hand edge.  The table is a lot wider than just the columns by themselves.  Is it possible to shrink the table width to just the width of the columns or am I making a feature request?

Comment: You should ask questions like how to do this, I doesn't make a lot of sense if you post questions like this

Comment: I've created an issue on the tabulator GitHub page https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2055

Comment: thats not a good way of creating a bug you should provide a working example

Answer (score 0):

If your columns have a fixed width, you should know the width your table needs to be... You can set the width in CSS or with a style tag in your html. So 8 x 50px columns needs a table width of 400px:

`<div id="example-table" style="width:400px"></div>`

or in CSS

```
#example-table{
    width:400px;
}
```

Sorry if I've misunderstood the question (I can't comment to clarify).